# Set day with no overflow (with PHP Carbon)

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I use Carbon (PHP library) to set day to a date. But I want it not going to the next month, but rather stop and the end of month.
Example:

```
Carbon::create(2018, 2, 27, 0, 0, 0)->day(31);
```

I'm getting

> 2018-03-03 00:00:00

But I need

> 2018-02-28 00:00:00

When you operate months Carbon gives you `->subMonthsNoOverflow()` and -`>addMonthsNoOverflow()` which is really helpful but there is nothing like this for setting a day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is

```
$day = 31;
$date = Carbon::create(2018, 2, 27, 0, 0, 0);
$date->day(min($day, $date->daysInMonth));
```

Comment: stable solution.

Answer (score 8):

Since Carbon 2.0 they have added a method `setUnitNoOverflow($unit, $value, $overflowUnit)` but it's still undocumented.

I managed to get 2019-02-28 by doing it like this

```php
Carbon::parse('2019-02-01')->setUnitNoOverflow('day', 31, 'month')->format('Y-m-d')
```

```php
 Carbon\Carbon @1551398399 {#3013
     date: 2019-02-28 23:59:59.999999 UTC (+00:00),
   }
```

Alternatively you can use `addUnitNoOverflow` and `subUnitNoOverflow`

[Issue github](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon/pull/1387#issuecomment-411296240) - 
[Source](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon/blob/2.27.0/src/Carbon/Traits/Date.php#L1334)

Comment: Don't know if it was previously undocumented, but the documentation has since been properly documented. [Carbon docs link](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-addsub) It's among the add and subtract date with an example for setting hour units without overflowing the day. Asume it won't overflow the month either, since month isn't overflowing.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I could have missed that in the doc as well.

Answer (score 2):

Can you use `endOfMonth()` instead?

```
Carbon::create(2018, 2, 27, 0, 0, 0)->endOfMonth();
```

There's a full list of modifiers in the [Carbon documentation](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-modifiers).

Comment: NO, what If I need it on 30-th? I need it on a day, not on an end of month.

Comment: February 30th does not exist, so `endOfMonth()` will give you Feb 28th (or 29th on a leap year). On other months that do contain 30 or 31 days, it will return that date, i.e., March 31st.

Comment: And on January I'll get 31-st instead of 30-th.

Comment: Yes, `Carbon::create(2018, 1, 27, 0, 0, 0)->endOfMonth();` would give you January 31st.

Comment: I need to set day to a date. Say I need 30-th. For januarry It will be '->day(30);' but for februarry it will fail.

Comment: @YevgeniyAfanasyev So you'd like to be able to set the 30th of every month, except February, which would be 28th (or 29th on leap years). Is that correct?

Comment: No, I want to set a day to a carbon instance. same way that carbon function  `->day($d)` works, but if the month does not have this day this function gives me another month, I don't want that, I want a last day of the month instead.

Answer (score -2):

Is very simple:

```php
$date = Carbon\Carbon::now();
$date->day = 10;
$date->month = 1;
$date->year = 2021;
```

Or

```php
Carbon\Carbon::parse("2021-10-01")
```

Docs: https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-setters

Comment: If you apply your solution to the given exemple in February, you will end up with the same overflow issue. This does not work any better.